# Finding server in LAN

Tags: python-3.x, server, lan

How to find, in python, server without having it's IP in LAN?
I assume that port will be configured in file so its doesn't have to find port.
 I tried to search on google but I couldn't find anything useful or that could help me with it. 
The server IP will be changing because it will not run constantly on the same computer.
So basically I got app with server that is on random computer in network, and I want to find its IP from another computer.
I would be really thankful for either explanation how to do it or link that could help me to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Not certain if this is what you want to do, I think you want to find the IP of a server by running some python execution on the server?

You could try :

```
from subprocess import call
  call (["ipconfig"])
```

This will dump the IP config and you can parse out the IP address.  This assumes a windows server.  You would have to modify the call for your OS.

---

Updated :

Check this out : [TCP Communications](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication) or [UDP Communications](http://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication) ... it looks like what you are looking for. You will still have the mess of determining the available addresses on the network (arp -a), and testing each one - this would be your client side app. Your server side app, when it receives the right query on the TCP or UDP port, would then determine it's address (ipconfig) and return the value.

Comment: Still a little confusing ... if you are on a remote computer and trying to find the address of another computer that is random and not known, there is no eloquent way to do this.

Comment: You could try substituting "arp -a" for "ipconfig", then interrogate each ip address returned to determine if it is the device you are looking for?

Comment: well its sohuld be something like small app to comunicate between computers in lan where client as well as server doesn't have constant IP. the problem is that i need to find server somehow

Comment: So you do not have an app already; you are looking to create an app to run on a remote server, and then locate that server / ip address from another machine on the same network?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want to do, but I have no idea how to start it

Comment: Check this out : https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication or https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication ... it looks like what you are looking for.  You will still have the mess of determining the available addresses on the network (arp -a), and testing each one - this would be your client side app.  Your server side app, when it receives the right query on the TCP or UDP port, would then determine it's address (ipconfig) and return the value.

Comment: @DanG: You should update  your answer with your last comment so we can upvote it.  ;)